# Cannot read property 'fontFamily' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("h2, a, img, p, ul, li");

var font = x[i].innerText.trim().style.fontFamily;
console.log(font);
```

Comment: You had this same question earlier. You were given solutions, too.

Comment: A string of text doesn’t have any `style` property.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
x[i].innerText.trim()
```

is a string, not a HTML element. It doesn't have `style` property. You can do simply

```
var font = x[i].style.fontFamily;
```

Comment: Thanks for the responding, made the above changes. But above error, I am getting against the empty string in x[I]. Console output: gives " " for var x. How to handle this?